# Button depending of 'If' function

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button

dummy here. I want to make a card game where you guess red or black for the first card. if you get it correct you get to guess the second card...and so on. I'm having trouble getting the second card to trigger. Mind taking a look? It's should be easy, and there's gotta be an easier way than the dumb, unsuccessful way that I tried.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redbutton);
    blackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blackbutton);

    card1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card1);
    card2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card2);

    int value1 = randomValue();
    TextView order = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order);

//Card 1, does work
    if (order.getText().toString().contains("Guess to Start!")||order.getText().toString().contains("Drink!")) {

        redButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView order = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order);
                int value1 = randomValue();

                if (value1 == 1) {
                    int res1 = getResources().getIdentifier("red", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card1.setImageResource(res1);
                    order.setText("Correct!");
                } else {
                    int res2 = getResources().getIdentifier("black", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card1.setImageResource(res2);
                    order.setText("Drink!");
                }}});


        blackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int value1 = randomValue();
                TextView order = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order);

                if (value1 == 1) {
                    int res1 = getResources().getIdentifier("red", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card1.setImageResource(res1);
                    order.setText("Drink!");
                } else {
                    int res2 = getResources().getIdentifier("black", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card1.setImageResource(res2);
                    order.setText("Correct!");
                }}});
    }


//Card 2 starts here; doesn't work
    if (order.getText().toString().contains("Correct!")) {

        redButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView order = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order);
                int value1 = randomValue();

                if (value1 == 1) {
                    int res1 = getResources().getIdentifier("red", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card2.setImageResource(res1);
                    order.setText("Correct!");
                } else {
                    int res2 = getResources().getIdentifier("black", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card2.setImageResource(res2);
                    order.setText("Drink!");
                }}});


        blackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int value1 = randomValue();
                TextView order = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order);

                if (value1 == 1) {
                    int res1 = getResources().getIdentifier("red", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card2.setImageResource(res1);
                    order.setText("Drink!");
                } else {
                    int res2 = getResources().getIdentifier("black", "drawable", "com.pjproductions.speedbump");
                    card2.setImageResource(res2);
                    order.setText("Correct!");
                }}});


    }

}


        public static int randomValue() {
            return RANDOM.nextInt(2) + 1;
        }
```

Comment: generating the next card and handling the click should be called in a recursively way on success

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that the "OnCreate" method is only called once. In your code, you try to switch between different behaviour on the rebButton & blackButton, but once the onClickListener is called in the onCreate, it will never be called again.

Do you follow me?

You would need to call a method in your onClickListeners and from there, adjust the behaviour based on "order.getText().contains(...)"

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redbutton);
   blackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blackbutton);

   card1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card1);
   card2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card2);

   int value1 = randomValue();
   TextView order = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order);

   redButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) { 
           redButonClick();
       }});


   blackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           blackButonClick();
        }});
}

private void redButtonClick(){
   //Which state am i in?!? Deal with it.
}

private void blackButtonClick(){
   //Which state am i in?!? Deal with it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be of the following form

```
// Have a guess
if (right) // Have another guess
else // Do something else and start again
```

My first question is does it matter if it's the first guess or a subsequent guess?

For example, if you put your card back after selecting it and shuffle the cards then if obviously doesn't matter.

My second question is is there anything different between a red guess and a black guess?

If the colour is just a property of the guess then there's no need to differentiate, simply pass it in as a parameter like this

```
guess(colour);
```

If my assumptions are correct then your problem can be broken down into something like this

```
redClick()
{
    guess(red)
}

blackClick()
{
    guess(black)
}

guess(colour)
{
    // Pick a card

    if (card == colour)
    {
        // Have another go
    }
    else
    {
        // Start again
    }
}
```

You have an event handler for your red and black buttons but they both call the same guess method. The guess method handles having a guess and comparing it to a result then prompts you to guess again or start again.